# iOS application build uploading issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-update

I have successfully uploaded my iOS build on App Store today. Its been more then **5 hours** now and the build is still not shown in Activities. I am using **Xcode 10.1** to upload build and uploaded build using Xcode update build option. What needs to be done. I have tried to upload the same build again, but got **"Redundant binary upload"** error.

Comment: Change build number and upload again, will not show you error. i.e. If `Version: 1.0`, than `build: 1.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I upload a version with build number 2 and it was totally disappeared, I didn't find it anywhere and I can not re-upload it. I upload another build with number 3. 
My app was approved and everything is okay. Today I received an email from Apple which said that I already have a build with a bigger version and I have to upload a new build bigger than 3.

I think somehow the service just hanged for a while(at least 2 days). But it hangs only the specific upload of build and it is not affecting the app.

You have several options:

1. Just wait
2. Create a new build with a bigger build number
3. Create a new version.

I did the second option and it was okay

Comment: Tried the second option. Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: At some point you will receive an email, "We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, <App name> <version> (<build>). Please correct the following issues, then upload again." But this is for the old hanged build, and you should not care about it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of the app for example if it was 1.0 -> change it to 1.0.1 or 1.1

But you don't have to change the build if the app is not published to the App Store yet. Also make sure the build has been changed inside the `.plist`, that happens sometimes.

when you upload through Xcode to iTunesConnect it's can take a lot of time to process your build so just wait and it'll be finished eventually.